# Laravel many-to-many polymorphic relationship - custom methods/relationships on pivot

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, pivot

I have an issue with a many-to-many polymorphic relationship (diagram below). In a food shop some products have options/variants, e.g. pizza comes in variants of 7inch, 12inch, 16inch. When pizza is added to cart a variant must be selected.

When an order is saved
 - bought products (without variants) are saved in the `orderables` table
 - variants that are bought are saved in `variant_orderables` table

[image: diagram of polymorphic many-to-many relationship]

Btw, the pivot tables are called `orderables` and `variant_orderables` instead of what you might expect according to Laravel conventions, e.g. "customer_order_product", because in addition to `customer_orders`, the `products` and `variants` are also in a polymorphic relationship with `stock_orders` (where the shop buys those items from suppliers). I just didn't show all that on the diagram to keep it simple.

Anyway, bought items, be they `products` or `variants`, can have "extras" added to them in the order. E.g. A pizza can have extra cheese, or pepperoni as extras (info contained in the `extras_groups_offers` table).

`ordered_extras` is where we will list the `product` or `variant` id of the extras that have been ordered, along with the `orderables` or `variant_orderables` id that the extras are applied on.

So between `variants` and `customer_orders`, `variant_orderables` is the pivot, but then `variant orderables` has a relationship with `extras_groups_offers` with `ordered_extras` as the pivot.

I know I probably need to do something with newPivot, but as this involves a few polymorphic many-to-many relationships, I'm not exactly sure how to go about it. If anyone could give me a simple example solution, I'd be very grateful.

Basically, I am trying to reach a stage where I can eager load all the necessary information for an order, including products/variants ordered, and all the ordered extras for each product/variant that has been ordered. I just don't know how to go about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've overcome the problem by making the `orderables` and `variant_orderables` tables as normal models.  This means I do have more chaining to do in terms of relationships, but I can at least eager load multiple nested layers easily, e.g. order.orderProducts.extrasGroupsOffers
(P.S. orderables has been renamed to order_product, if you're wondering where that came from)

Comment: Hi. I am kind of facing a similar situation to this. Could you check if my question is similar to yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68073778/laravel-polymorphic-many-to-many-relationship-pivot-table-with-relationship-to-a Also any feedback on how well the above solution worked?