# Laravel Polymorphic Many-to-Many relationship pivot table with relationship to another Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, polymorphic-associations

I have the following table structure as shown in the diagram:
[image: database diagram]

Briefly, it is composed of several many-to-many polymorphic relationships as described:

- many `resources` can have many `sources` and the pivot table `sourceables` contains `catalog_number` and `lot_number` information to make each row in the pivot table unique. Many resources could also come from the same source or from different sources, differentiated by the catalog number and lot number on the pivot table.
- many `resources` can also have many `publications` attached to it, through the `publicationables` table with `notes` on the pivot table
- a resource's source could also be described in many publications.

My questions:

1. Since the resource's source is differentiated by the pivot table `sourceables` how should I save the relationship between the pivot rows of `sourceables` to the `publications`?
2. Can you have a custom intermediate table models between both `sourceables` and 'publicationables' to link to the `publications`?
3. How to retrieve a resource with all it's publications and also with the sources with all corresponding publications?

Comment: I'm planning to reply to this tonight or this afternoon.

Comment: Thank you @RicardoVargas. Please let me know if any clarification is required.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay, I just working to finish my answer. I was able to create a full Github repository with live samples for you. I will finish all the details in the morning.

Comment: No problem. I am just happy that you are attempting to help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my answer and I hope that I can bring some light to your problem. I already publish a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ricardov03/polyrelations) with an example of all the code I write here. I add more information about how to replicate my scenario there.

### The Database and The Relations

Here is my interpretation of the Database and its relations. You can check all the Migrations on the repository.
[image]

### The Solution

#### Question 1:

How should I save the relationship between the pivot rows of sourceable to the publications?

##### Answer:

Before proceeding with the code example, I would like to explain some important concepts to understand. I'm going to use the expression **tag** to refer to the **identifier** or **index** Morph Relations used to relate models.
The way this works, it's by assigning the tag to any Model you want to add into a relation. Any model using these tags can be store in the Morph Pivot Table. Laravel uses the _"modelable"*type* column to filter the call on the relations storing the Model Name. You can "tag" your Model with a Relation creating a method into the Model that returns the morphToMany relation function.

For this specific case, here's how to proceed:
In your Resource Model, you have two methods, one related to the  *sourceable* index and the other with the *publicationable* tag using **morphToMany** in return.
Here's how it's look the Resource Model (./app/Models/Resource.php):

```php
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Resource extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function publications()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Publication::class, 'publicationable')->withPivot('notes');
    }

    public function sources()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Source::class, 'sourceable')->withPivot(['catalog_number', 'lot_number']);
    }
}
```

In your Publication Model, you have two methods, one related to the  *sourceable* index and the other with the *inverse relation* with the Resource Method to the *publicationable* tag using **morphedByMany** in return.
Here's how it looks the Publication Model (./app/Models/Publication.php):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Publication extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function sources()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Source::class, 'sourceable')->withPivot(['catalog_number', 'lot_number']);
    }

    public function resources()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Resource::class, 'publicationable');
    }
}
```

```
With this, you can be able to accomplish your goal of relating Publications with Resources and Sources.
```

#### Question 2: Can you have an intermediate table between both *sourceable* and *publicationable* to link to the publications?

##### Answer:

No, you don't need to. You can use the *sourceables* table to accomplish this. You can always relate a Source with ANY model by creating the method that returns the **morphToMany** relation to the Source model. These what we do with Publications on **Question 1**.

#### Question 3: How to retrieve a resource with all its publications and the sources with all corresponding publications?

##### Answer:

I think Eloquent it's my favorite feature on the whole Laravel Framework. This the cherry on the cake with all we do on the Model definition.

If you check the Resource and Publication Model definition again, we add a *withPivot()* method with the related field we want to include on any call we do to the relation with eloquent. This method made it possible to read custom values from the Pivot table.

IMPORTANT: For this example, I'm implicitly adding the pivot values because I don't declare those columns as NULL on the migrations.

To relate (Store on the Pivot table) a publication with a resource using the relation, you just need to:

###### (Using **artisan tinker**)

```sh
Psy Shell v0.10.8 (PHP 8.0.6 — CLI) by Justin Hileman
>>> $publication = \App\Models\Publication::find(5)
>>> $resource = \App\Models\Resource::find(19)
>>> $resource->publications()->attach($publication, ["notes" => "Eureka!"]);
### Adding another Publication
>>> $publication = \App\Models\Publication::find(10)
>>> $resource->publications()->attach($publication, ["notes" => "Eureka 2!"]);
```

###### (Using a Controller)

```php
use App\Models\Resource;
use App\Models\Publication;
...
$id_resource = 1; // This is the Resource Id you want to reach.
$id_publication = 10; // This is the Resource Id you want to reach.

$resource = Resource::find($id_resource);
$publication = Publication::find($id_publication);
$pivotData = [ "notes" => "Eureka!" ];

$resource->publications()->attach($publication, $pivotData);
```

To retrieve all publications from a resource, you just need to:

###### (Using **artisan tinker**)

```sh
Psy Shell v0.10.8 (PHP 8.0.6 — CLI) by Justin Hileman
>>> $resource = \App\Models\Publication::find(5)
>>> $resource->publications()->get();
```

Easy right? :) Eloquent POWER!

###### (Using a Controller)

```php
use App\Models\Resource;
...
$id_resource = 1; // This is the Resource Id you want to reach.
$resource = Resource::find($id_resource);

$resource->publications()->get();
```

Just in case of any doubt, this is how you can store and retrieve from all the models:

###### (Using a Controller)

```
use App\Models\Publication;
use App\Models\Resource;
use App\Models\Source;
...
... Method ...
$id_publication = 1;
$id_resource = 1;
$id_source = 1;

$publication = Publication::find($id_resource);
$resource = Resource::find($id_resource);
$source = Source::find($id_resource);

$publicationPivotColumns = [
    "notes" => "This is a note...",
];

$sourcePivotColumns = [
    "catalog_number" => 100,
    "lot_number" => 4903,
];

// Storing Data
// Attach (Store in the publicationables table) a Publication to a Resource
$resource->publications()->attach($publication, $publicationPivotColumns);

// Attach (Store in the sourceables table) a Source to a Resource
$resource->sources()->attach($source, $sourcePivotColumns);

// Attach (Store in the sourceables table) a Source to a Publication
$publication->sources()->attach($source, $sourcePivotColumns);

// Retraiving Data
// Get all Sources from a Resource
$resource->sources()->get();

// Get all Publications from a Resource
$resource->publications()->get();

// Get all Sources from a Publication
$publication->sources()->get();
```

Comment: Hi Ricardo. Thank you for taking the time to extensively cover the topic. My main issue still with your solution is the following. I do not have `sources` related to `publications`. I have a relationship between `sourceables` and `publications`, i.e. rows in the `sourceables` table should be related to `publications` table. So things with a unique combination of `source_id`, `catalog_number` and `lot_number` would be linked to many `publications`.

Comment: You still be able to do this in my provided solution by just setting the ```catalog_number``` and the ```lot_number``` to nullable() on the migration. And then you just need to pass the required additional information when you add a source into Publication. This allows you to avoid the need for an additional table to store this data.

Comment: Trying to understand better y think I get it. You just need to add another relation between the Publication and the Resource Models to accomplish this. I could add more details tonight.

Comment: I think I have to redesign the architecture. So instead of having a poly many-many relationship between `resources` to `sources`, I think I should have 3 tables: `resources` poly one-many `source_items` & `source_items` many-one `sources`. Then I can relate `source_items` to `publications` via `publicationable`. Thoughts?

Comment: To rephrase my question in terms of tagging - How do I `tag` a row in the `sourceables` table to a `publication`?

Comment: @Coola sorry, I was unable to answer until now. Let me try to understand your last comments.

Comment: Ok, I just need to understand the relationship between a publication and the sourceables item to identify if you need  a one-to-one or one-to-many relation.

Comment: Let me try to explain the why about the relation. You can easily accomplish this just by adding a new column on the ```publications``` table and then adding a one-to-one relationship from the sourceable table. If you need that one publication has more than one ```sourceables```, you need to add a new table called ```publications_sourceables``` and add a many-to-many relation on the publication's model. With this, you can accomplish your goal. Please let me know the required relation and I can add a new answer for you.

Comment: Each `sourceable` can have multiple `publications` and each `publication` can belong to many `sourceables` but also can belong to other models like `resources`. I hope that answers your question and hopefully you can provide a solution then.

Comment: @Coola Thanks so much for the award. I'm currently trying to respond with a code sample of your requirement. I will be working with you on this until you find the best solution for your issue.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. I didn't want the bounty to just disappear so I went ahead and gave it to you. You have clearly put effort for this so that's the least I could do. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again for this. I'm sorry for the delay in my answer. I'm currently working on a Project final delivery and I don't know why the final part of any project takes so much effort to finish. Please let me know If you can check the pending alternative answer on the weekend. Let me know if you even prefer a Zoom to check the test on your own project.